# Select most recent row with count of all the entries for a pair of values

Tags: mysql

I have to display a list of meetings between two candidates, in which i have to display the date, time of the latest meeting between two candidates along with count of all the meetings that has been arranged between them.

Query I have written to select the meetings between the candidates:

```
SELECT cm.id AS meeting_id, cm.meeting_date, cm.meeting_time, cm.candidate1_id, cm.candidate2_id
            FROM candidate_meetings AS cm                                   
            JOIN view_candidate_details AS candidate_1 ON candidate_1.id = cm.candidate1_candidate_id
            JOIN view_candidate_details AS candidate_2 ON candidate_2.id = cm.candidate2_candidate_id
            WHERE (candidate_1.counselor_member_id = 41 OR candidate_2.counselor_member_id = 41)
            ORDER BY cm.id DESC
```

which gives the following ouptput:

```
+------------+--------------+--------------+------------------+-----------------+
| meeting_id | meeting_date | meeting_time | candidate1_id    | candidate2_id   |
+------------+--------------+--------------+------------------+-----------------+
|          6 | 2016-08-31   | 17:45:00     |               24 |              28 |
|          5 | 2016-08-31   | 17:30:00     |               24 |              28 |
|          4 | 2016-08-31   | 19:30:00     |               24 |              23 |
|          3 | 2016-08-31   | 18:30:00     |               24 |              22 |
|          2 | 2016-08-31   | 19:15:00     |               24 |              21 |
|          1 | 2016-08-31   | 17:15:00     |               24 |              21 |
+------------+--------------+--------------+------------------+-----------------+
```

Now to get the count along with details of most recent meeting between two candidates, I am adding this to query:

```
SELECT *, count(*) AS meeting_count                                
        FROM                                                                
        (                                                                   
            SELECT cm.id AS meeting_id, cm.meeting_date, cm.meeting_time, cm.candidate1_id, cm.candidate2_id
            FROM candidate_meetings AS cm                                   
            JOIN view_candidate_details AS candidate_1 ON candidate_1.id = cm.candidate1_candidate_id
            JOIN view_candidate_details AS candidate_2 ON candidate_2.id = cm.candidate2_candidate_id
            WHERE (candidate_1.counselor_member_id = 41 OR candidate_2.counselor_member_id = 41)
            ORDER BY cm.id DESC             
        ) as sub                                                            
        GROUP BY sub.candidate1_id, sub.candidate2_id;
```

After running this query I am getting this result:

```
+------------+--------------+--------------+------------------+-----------------+---------------+
| meeting_id | meeting_date | meeting_time | candidate1_id    | candidate2_id   | meeting_count |
+------------+--------------+--------------+------------------+-----------------+---------------+
|          1 | 2016-08-31   | 17:15:00     |               24 |              21 |             2 |
|          3 | 2016-08-31   | 18:30:00     |               24 |              22 |             1 |
|          4 | 2016-08-31   | 19:30:00     |               24 |              23 |             1 |
|          5 | 2016-08-31   | 17:30:00     |               24 |              28 |             2 |
+------------+--------------+--------------+------------------+-----------------+---------------+
```

But the expected result is

```
+------------+--------------+--------------+------------------+-----------------+---------------+
| meeting_id | meeting_date | meeting_time | candidate1_id    | candidate2_id   |meeting_count  |
+------------+--------------+--------------+------------------+-----------------+---------------+
|          6 | 2016-08-31   | 17:45:00     |               24 |              28 |             2 |
|          4 | 2016-08-31   | 19:30:00     |               24 |              23 |             1 |
|          3 | 2016-08-31   | 18:30:00     |               24 |              22 |             1 |
|          2 | 2016-08-31   | 19:15:00     |               24 |              21 |             2 |
+------------+--------------+--------------+------------------+-----------------+---------------+
```

**PS: Please ignore the order of the id column in the expected result.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason of the difference between actual outputs and expected outputs is the fact that you are not telling MySQL that you want the latest meeting date. Your query is against the sql standards because you have fields in the select list that are neither in the group by list, nor are subject of an aggregate function such as `max()`.

MySQL under certain sql mode settings allow such queries to run, however the [value of such fields is indeterminate](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-handling.html).

The best solution is to explicitly tell MySQL what you need:

```
SELECT  max(concat(cm.meeting_date, cm.meeting_time)) as latest_meeting_time, cm.candidate1_id, cm.candidate2_id
        FROM candidate_meetings AS cm                                   
        JOIN view_candidate_details AS candidate_1 ON candidate_1.id = cm.candidate1_candidate_id
        JOIN view_candidate_details AS candidate_2 ON candidate_2.id = cm.candidate2_candidate_id
        WHERE (candidate_1.counselor_member_id = 41 OR candidate_2.counselor_member_id = 41)
        GROUP BY cm.candidate1_id, cm.candidate2_id
```

If you want additional field values from the `candidate_meetings` table from the latest meetings' records, then place the above query in a subquery and join it back to your `candidate_meetings` table in the outer query on the `concat(candidate_meetings.meeting_date, candidate_meetings.meeting_time)=subquery_alias.latest_meeting_time` join condition.

Comment: Thanks for showing the right path as well as +1 for giving knowledge about sql standards.

Answer (score -1):

Try this one:

```
SELECT *, count(*) AS meeting_count                                
FROM                                                                    
    (SELECT cm.id AS meeting_id, cm.meeting_date, cm.meeting_time, cm.candidate1_id, cm.candidate2_id
    FROM candidate_meetings AS cm                                   
    JOIN view_candidate_details AS candidate_1 ON candidate_1.id = cm.candidate1_candidate_id
    JOIN view_candidate_details AS candidate_2 ON candidate_2.id = cm.candidate2_candidate_id
    WHERE (candidate_1.counselor_member_id = 41 OR candidate_2.counselor_member_id = 41)
    ORDER BY cm.id             
) as sub                                                            
GROUP BY sub.candidate1_id, sub.candidate2_id
ORDER BY cm.id DESC
```

You get your expected result wrong because when you use the GROUP BY clause, the database select the last occurrence of the meeting_id, meeting_date, meeting_time.

Comment: This "solution" is against the sql standards and will only work under certain sql mode settings only in mysql. In the recent versions of MySQL the default settings will prevent such queries from running.